# StackOverflowError when i serialize an object

Tags: java, serialization, stack-overflow

I want to seriliaze an object with this method :

```
public void serializ(CRDT m) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOutput);
    stream.writeObject(m);
    sumMemory = byteOutput.size();

    stream.flush();
    stream.close();
    byteOutput.flush();
    byteOutput.close();
}
```

I have an exception `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1169)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    ...
```

I read some forum that i need to reimplementing the `writeObject / readObject` methods.
Is it the only possible solution ? and how to reimplementing the `writeObject / readObject`

My object to serialize is : 
http://pastebin.com/D1kEidtn

Two class that cause errors are :
[pastebin.com/Sb3X0Quq](http://www.pastebin.com/Sb3X0Quq) and [enter link description here](http://www.pastebin.com/cw15LQ1z)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post tghe code of the object you want to serialize. And I would recommend to use a BufferedOutputStream.

Comment: Show us the `myObject` class.

Comment: @area404 and Rohit Jain
I edited my question !

Comment: And don't blame this site for you problems!

Comment: Since `CRDT` is `abstract` we need also the code of the concrete class.

Comment: What A.H. says. And I would recommend to use Integer instead of int. Do all classes implement Serializable?

Comment: It's a great project i cannot diplay it all !
@area404 if i use BufferedOutputStream how to retreive a size of  serialization ?

Yes all classes implement Serializable :-)

Comment: Do you need the size? Maybe your object is to big to save it complete in one output stream. A buffered stream could help.

Comment: are there observers added to the object you're serializing?

Comment: @area404 yes it's great ! but if i use BufferedOutputStream ! how can i retreive the size of serialization ? (memory ocupation)

Comment: @Mehdi: If you cannot post the code of the concrete class then you should try to strip down the code to the relevant parts. Of course the best thing would be if you can provide us with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) example.

Comment: Just print out the class of the object causing the problem and then analyze the code of that class. Good chance is, you'll find the problem yourself.

Comment: My code is in these two links:
http://pastebin.com/Sb3X0Quq
http://pastebin.com/cw15LQ1z

Comment: Need the code for your Document and VectorClock classes as well. You can probably find out the offending object(s) yourself with a decent debugger (if you have the source code distribution of the JVM you are using).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CRDT is the superclass of the Object m which is serialized.
The error is that the class that derives from CRDT seems to have a reference to itself, leading to an endless recursion
You see that in the stack trace.
Tipp find out the class of The object CRDT m: by either using the debugger, or adding an System.out.println(m.getClass()) at the beginn of your serialize() method.
Then when you know the class, check wheter the object has a reference to itself.

Comment: The infinite recursion may also, and I actually think this is the case, by caused by a large linked data structure, which causes a large recursion on java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields.

Comment: @Herbert I don't think so, because linking means referencing, and referenced Objects are kept in a table during serialisation to avoid duplicate output of objects.

Comment: The use of a table does not contradict the use of recursion and hence does not contradict the possibility of a stack overflow, in fact, this is a very common 'bug' (I consider it a bug of java, but some may consider it a feature): http://ideone.com/wATlNK

Comment: @Herbert One could implement serialisation such that endless loops are avoided. But this would be a major slowdown. Interesting code you posted. That could indeed be seen as a bug. I personaly dont trust the Object restore mechanism, I replace referecnes with ids, and restore them myself after deserialisation.

Comment: @Herbert, but now I see that you are right, the Exeption is most probably caused by the default serialisation. i chnaged my answer

Comment: I also consider this a bug, and I also filed a bug report at oracle, with unfortunately zero response. Correlation between the maximum stack size and the maximum object depth when serializing seems to be an unwanted 'java feature'. PS: I don't have a link to the bug, as these bug reports seem to be private to Oracle.

Comment: @Herbert, now I thought and read a bit further: It is not a bug: The structure in your linked describes a recursive data structure. And with all recursive taks, there is an limited number of stack space. And there is no known algorithm that universally tranforms any recursion into a iterative approach. When having recursivce structures leading to a very deep stack, you better serialize them yourself.

Comment: actually, there is, one could create a stack (not the call-stack but a LinkedList or something like that) of objects which still need to be serialized. In general, each recursive algorithm can be written iteratively by using a stack as a replacement for the call stack.

Comment: @Herbert, yes each recursive algo can be written iterarively, but there is no algorithm in the world than can automatically transform a recursive algorithm into a iterative one. As long as such does not exist, one can always find an example where a "clever" serialisation would throw an Stackoverflow.

Comment: Why would you want this algorithm rewrite to be done automatically?

Comment: @Herbert: you dont understand the problem, read and understand the link you posted above. ideone.com/wATINK. To answer: because java serialsiation is an automatic process involving handling the structure of a class with (multiple) recursive references.

Comment: I created some java-like pseudo-code which should be capable of serializing without the constraint of call stack sizes: http://ideone.com/KmYeLr . I really don't see what you mean by 'java serialization is an automated process involving the structure of a class with multiple recursive references'. I don't see why "adding something to a stack" is impossible if "calling a member function" is not.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted your concrete classes so its hard to spot the error but 
In short, any recursive algorithm can overflow the stack and stack is finite.
 For deeply nested object graphs  Java builtin serlialization requires excessive stack space.
for elaborate details refer 
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JavaSerializationIsBroken
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JavaSerializationAndTheStack

Answer (score 1):

i juste add `-Xss512m` to Netbeans and it's work :D

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I had same issue but looks like mine was related to checkpoint duration being too big. It appear, Spark maintains some sort of object linkage while writing it out and if the duration is too big it will get stack overflown.